# playing a sound doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios-simulator, audio

I've added a sound to my app. 
In my .h i've added:

```
CFURLRef soundFileURL;
SystemSoundID soundFile;
```

in my viewDidLoad in my .m:

```
soundFileURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(
        CFBundleGetMainBundle(),
        CFSTR("sound"),
        CFSTR("mp3"),
        NULL);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(
        soundFileURL,
        &soundFile);
```

and lastly i've added a -playSound method:

```
-(void)playSound {

NSLog(@"playSound");
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(soundFile); }
```

It works fine on the iPhone Simulator, but when I build the app on my iPhone the console says the sound was played but it wasn't. 
I read that many others had this problem too but I didn't find any solutions.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your encoding - the audio codecs on the simulator are much different than those provided by your actual iPhone hardware.  Try reencoding.

Also - you don't want to use an mp3 for a sound, you want to use a non-compressed file format (I suggest aiff from experience) because there isn't dedicated decoding hardware to support the sound decoding you're trying to do.  (There is for playing music, which mp3 is recommended for)

Comment: thank you very much, but now there's another problem: every time the sound is played, the iphone vibrates. what's wrong?

Comment: No idea but "PlayAlertSound" looks suspect.  Perhaps this is meant to also buzz the device?   Sounds like another question.  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioPlayer) in the `AVFoundation` framework. It has a simple asynchronous interface for sound playback on iOS.

Check out the Apple programming guide [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It turned out I was referencing "Horn.caf" with

```
NSURL *hornSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"horn"
                                                withExtension: @"caf"];
```

Note the difference in case; My OS X Lion install is on a case insensitive file system.
Changing the code to the following fixed the issue.

```
NSURL *hornSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"Horn"
                                                withExtension: @"caf"];
```

Hope that helps others.